# bootstrap sidebar on hover show submenu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this sidebar in bootstrap

JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/akcncxqb/

```
<div class="portfolio-home">
            <div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
              <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
                  <div class="portfolio-menu-content">
                    <ul class="nav">
                    <li><center><h1><img src="/small-logo.png" height="30" width="40px"></h1>FexFree</center></li>
                      <li><center><h1><i class="fa fa-home fa-5"></i></h1>Home</center></li>
                      <li>
                        <center>
                            <h1>
                                <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-5"></i>
                            </h1>Projects
                        </center>
                         <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                    <li><center><h1><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-5"></i></h1>Gallery</center></li>
                                                    <li><center><h1><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-5"></i></h1>Contact</center></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><center><h1><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-5"></i></h1>Gallery</center></li>
                      <li><center><h1><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-5"></i></h1>Contact</center></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div><!--/row-offcanvas -->
        </div>
```

on hover of the products I want to display sub-menu right to the sidebar not below the menu
I want the sub-menu to the right side of the sidebar menu item projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/akcncxqb/1/

```
 .portfolio-home {
     min-width: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     /*max-height: 100%;*/
     /*background-image: url('/home/slider/user_back.png');*/
 }

 .portfolio-menu-content {
     margin: 10px;
 }

 .portfolio-menu-content i,
 .portfolio-menu-content li {
     color: #fff;
     cursor: pointer;
 }

 .portfolio-menu-content h1 {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

 #sidebar {
     min-width: 120px;
     max-width: 120px;
     background-color: #3CC122;
     /*float: left;*/
     margin-left: 5%;
     min-height: 60%;
     max-height: 60%;
     position: relative;

 }

 .sub-menu {
     background-color: green;
     display: none;
     list-style: outside none none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 20px;
     position: absolute;
     right: -89px;
     top: -18px;
 }

 .nav>li:hover .sub-menu {
     display: block;
 }

 .portfolio-menu-content {
     margin: 10px 0;
 }
```